# Proof verification: $[L_1L_2:K] \leq [L_1:K][L_2:K]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory

Let $K \subseteq L_1,L_2 \subseteq L$ be fields. I want to show the following:
$$[L_1L_2:K] \leq [L_1:K][L_2:K]$$

---

**My attempt:**
The definition of $$L_1L_2:=L_1(L_2):=\bigcap \{F:F\text{ is a subfield of }L\text{ and }L_1 \subseteq F\text{ and }L_2 \subseteq F\}$$

$$\begin{split}
[L_1L_2:K]&=\dim_K L_1L_2\\
[L_1:K]&=\dim_K L_1\\
[L_2:K]&=\dim_K L_2\\
\end{split}$$

I know that the $K$-vector space $L_1L_2$ is a linear subspace of the $K$-vector space $L$.
The same is true for the $K$-vector spaces $L_1,L_2$.

From linear algebra, I know the following theorem:
$$\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim U_1 +\dim U_2 - \dim (U_1  \cap U_2)$$

If I can show that $L_1L_2= U_1+U_2$, the result should follow.
Now I have to show that $L_1L_2=U_1+U_2$

Rewriting the definition of
$$L_1L_2:=L_1(L_2):=\bigcap \{F:F\text{ is subfield of }L\text{ and }L_1 \cup L_2 \subseteq F\}$$

This means that $L_1 \cup L_2 \in L_1L_2$. From linear algebra, I know that $\operatorname{span}(U_1 \cup U_2)=U_1+U_2$.
Thus, $L_1L_2=U_1+U_2$ and thus $[L_1L_2:K] \leq [L_1:K][L_2:K]$ holds.

---

**My Question:**
Is my answer correct?

Comment: Suppose $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is a basis of $L_1$ and $f_1, \ldots, f_m$ is a basis of $L_2$. If you can show that the $e_i f_j$ generate $L_1 L_2$, then the result follows.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I am a little bit lost right now, how could I show that?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Since $E:=\{e_1,...,e_n\} \subset L_1$ and $F:=\{f_1,...,F_n\} \subset L_2$, $E \cup F \subset L_1L_2$ but how do I show that it generates $L_1L_2$. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: What does a generic element of $L_1 L_2$ look like? Expand it in terms of the bases for $L_1$ and $L_2$. Combine like terms. Each term should now look like $k e_i f_j$ for some $k \in K$.

Comment: In general, a good place to start to understand some construction is to try to explicitly write down a generic element.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Thats my problem, I don't know how a generic element of $L_1L_2$ looks like. Could you explain this to me?

Comment: Before you are ready for this problem, you should prove that $L_1 L_2 = \{a_1 b_1 + \cdots a_k b_k : k \in \mathbb{N}, a_i \in L_1, b_i \in L_2\}$. Clearly the latter set is a subset of $L_1 L_2$. Can you show that it's the whole thing?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins no I don't think so

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I don't really see what I am missing

Comment: Does this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862419/generic-element-of-compositum-of-two-fields